# convergence of infinite sequence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

> given the following sequence:
>
> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln^{\alpha+1}{(n+1)}}$
>
> for which values of $\alpha$ the sequence convergences?

I tried to use the integral test.
I defined $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\ln^{\alpha+1}{(x+1)}}$ and then used comparison test with $g(x)=\frac{1}{x\ln^{\alpha+1}x}$:

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{\ln{x}}{\ln{(x+1)}})^{\alpha+1}=1$.

How I continue from here?

Comment: Since $n \ln^{\alpha+1} (n+1) \sim n \ln^{\alpha+1} n$, you can use the comparison test with a function whose primitive is easily found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write the series instead as
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1) \log^{\alpha + 1} n}.$$
Now using the Cauchy condensation test we have that this series converges if and only if the series
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^n}{(2^n - 1) \log^{\alpha + 1} (2^n)} = \frac{1}{\log^{\alpha + 1} 2} \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^n}{2^n - 1} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{\alpha + 1}}$$
converges. Now $1 \le \frac{2^n}{2^n - 1} \le 2$, so we see that $\alpha > 0$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for the convergence.

Comment: is it possible to solve this without Cauchy condensation test?

Comment: @EMDB1: An analogous way would be to approximate with an integral $\int \frac{dx}{(x-1) \log^{\alpha + 1} x}$ and use the substitution $x = e^y$. But what's wrong with Cauchy condensation test? It's more elementary than comparing with integrals.